# how to store an audio file to internal storage in android

Tags: android, file, audio, uri, android-internal-storage

I have been googling alot of solutions and they dont work. Im not quite familiar yet with Uri,paths being pass on to the functions and Inputstreams in/out in storing file.

My project allows the user to attach an audio file from the external storage, and get its Uri

from button setOnclick

```
acs.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
                    lol, "Open Audio (mp3) file"), RQS_OPEN_AUDIO_MP3);
```

---

(this is from onActivityResult function)

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == RQS_OPEN_AUDIO_FX) {
            audioFxUri = data.getData();
        }
}
```

What i want to do after is store the audio to its internal storage.

Can you help with the code for storing audio files in internal storage? 
Also does it have it go through the process of File to bytearray then byte array to file(with the location of internal storage)?

Im just basing from what i have seen so far.  Hope you code help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy it to application files dir: `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`

```
public Uri copyFile(Uri uri){

    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().getType(uri));

    String fileName = "some_name" + "." + extension;

    File tempFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), fileName);

    try {

        boolean fileCreated = tempFile.createNewFile();

        if(!fileCreated){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"error creating file");
        }

        InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        if(inputStream != null){
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
        }
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception caught: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    return Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
}
```

Comment: i tried using the code but it returns null on the extension :/